# Mixpanel - Get Users(distinct_id or other property) based on Events tracked

Tags: javascript, php, rest, mixpanel

I have been trying to find the correct api to get the 'list of users' who have done an 'Event'.

For example there is an event called 'Created Profile' tracked in mixpanel and I want to get the list of users who have done this event between a date range,

I am using this API provided by them https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/data-export-api#libs-php

I have found that 'live' api is working close to my requirement but its doesn't support date range..Sample 'live' api req,

```
$api_key = 'XXX';
$api_secret = 'XXX';
$this->load->library('mixpanel_export');
$this->mixpanel_export->init($api_key, $api_secret);

$data = $this->mixpanel_export->request(array('live'), array(
                    'event' => 'Received Rating',
                    'on' => '5 in properties["level"]',
                    'start_time' => 0
                ));
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the script here helps you

https://gist.github.com/dawalama/34155428ff8f53e4d508

```
<?php

// Based on https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/exporting-raw-data-you-inserted-into-mixpanel
class MixpanelExport {

    private $api_url = 'https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export';
    private $api_key;
    private $api_secret;
    public $debug;

    public function __construct($api_key, $api_secret) {
        $this->api_key = $api_key;
        $this->api_secret = $api_secret;
        $this->debug = false;
    }

    public function export($params) {

        if (empty($params)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!isset($params['api_key'])) {
            $params['api_key'] = $this->api_key;
        }

        if (!isset($params['expire'])) {
            $current_utc_time = time() - date('Z');
            $params['expire'] = $current_utc_time + 100000; // Default 10 minutes
        }

        $sig = $this->signature($params);
        $request_url = $this->api_url . '?sig=' . $sig . '&'. http_build_query($params);

        if ($this->debug) {
            echo "\nURI: $request_url\n";
        }

        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);
        return $data;
    }

    private function signature($params) {
        /**
         * Algorithm to generate signature
         *
         * args = all query parameters going to be sent out with the request 
         * (e.g. api_key, unit, interval, expire, format, etc.) excluding sig.
         *
         * args_sorted = sort_args_alphabetically_by_key(args)
         *
         * args_concat = join(args_sorted) 
         *
         * # Output: api_key=ed0b8ff6cc3fbb37a521b40019915f18&event=["pages"]
         * #         expire=1248499222&format=json&interval=24&unit=hour
         *
         * sig = md5(args_concat + api_secret)
         **/
        ksort($params);
        $param_string = '';
        foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
            $param_string .= $key . '=' . $value;
        }
        return md5($param_string . $this->api_secret);
    }
}

/** Example usage
 *
 * $api_key = "<your api key>";
 * $api_secret = "<your secret key>";
 * $params = [
 * 'from_date'=>'2014-01-01',
 * 'to_date'=>'2014-02-01',
 * 'event'=>["event-x"]
 * ];
 *
 * $exporter = new MixpanelExport($api_key, $api_secret);
 * echo $exporter->export($params);
 **
```

You have to use the endpoint described here https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/exporting-raw-data-you-inserted-into-mixpanel